# ¿Qué significa 'aparecer entre los peces' en "Oda Al Amor Efimero" de Tulsa?

Tags: locuciones, letras-de-canciones, significado-en-contexto

Estaba [escuchando](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFxhTNmDHHw) [a esta canción](https://www.letras.com/tulsa/oda-al-amor-efimero/):

> Podría pasarme la vida lamiéndome las heridas
>
> Y aún no cicatrizarían
>
> Mejor me levanto y salgo de este estéril letargo
>
> Y vuelvo a empezar a empezar a creer que hay alguna opción de ganar
>
> No me importa si eres listo o idiota, te voy a querer igual

> **Si [apareces](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/aparecer), ahora mismo entre los [peces](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/peces)**, te voy a perdonar
>
> cualquier pecado mortal

Ya sé que significan el verbo y el sustantivo. Sin embargo, no tengo ni idea qué puede significar la locución **aparecer entre los peces**. Supongo que puede significar *inesperadamente* pero no soy seguro - no he encontrado nada en ningún diccionario.

Comment: Si el texto que aparece al principio del video tiene algo que ver, es simplemente estar en un barco mirando al mar y que alguien aparezca de repente.

Comment: Alguien entre los peces seria muerto.

Comment: Como una sirena....jaja. El chico apareció entre los arboles al fondo del jardín.